# ESP32 : WifiClient.connect() always return true

Tags: c++, esp32

I'm using the `ESP32-devkitC` to communicate using WiFi with a program on my computer. It's working fine. 
But that if that program is executed (nothing is listening on the port) when I use `connect("IP", port)` it is still connecting. And I have an error on the ESP when I try to send something.

I tried to use a random IP on the function `connect()` and it's connecting as well after some time.

Is there a way to avoid this behavior ?

Here is my code :
I'm using visual studio code and platformIO.

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <WiFi.h>


WiFiClient client;

void setup() 
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
    WiFi.begin("SSID", "PASS");
    WiFi.setSleep(false);
    while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
        // Check to see if connecting failed.
        // This is due to incorrect credentials
        if (WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECT_FAILED) {
            Serial.println("Failed to connect to WIFI. Please verify credentials: ");
        }
        delay(5000);
    }
    Serial.println("Wifi status :");
    Serial.println(WiFi.status());
    if (client.connect("192.168.1.101", 2222)) // always true
    {
        Serial.print("connected");
        client.print("Some string");
    }
    else{
        Serial.println("Error");
    }
}

void loop() 
{ 

}
```

I expect the connection to fail and jumping to the else statement.

Comment: The `nothing is listening on the port` doesn't mean the port is blocked. What if you did check `client.is_connected()` ?

Comment: @KamilCuk Thanks for your answer. It was exactly that (i guess you meant `client.connected()`).

Comment: And it returns false? Wonder then what does `connect()` really do? I guessed it does asynchronously connects - `connect()` only is a "request to connect", while the real connecting part is done in the background, but that's a guess. But even the [arduino docs](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/WiFiClientConnected) do `if (client.connect(server, 80)) {  Serial.println("connected");` suggesting it is connected right after `connect()`, and then they use only `client.connected()` to see if it's disconnected. Maybe you can ask on https://arduino.stackexchange.com/

Comment: `client.connected()` does return false when if no connection was established. As I said in the post, `connect()` always return true no matter the arguments which is weird. I don't know how my computer (Ubuntu 19.04) behave receiving the connection from the ESP (even through a telnet connection is refused). I'll ask as you suggested.

Comment: I'm having the same issue... :( client.connect() returns true even if there is no Internet..... Any conclusion here?

Comment: @Adi Nistor I still i no idea why `client.connect()`always returns true, but you can check if the connection worked by using ``client.connected()`.